# ADX external tables - connect an ADLSgen2 Table `?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, external-tables

Is it possible to create a Kusto external table that is connected to an Azure storage account ?

The idea is not to connect a csv or parquet file in a container, but an **ADLSgen2 Table** like this:

```
.create external table ExternalTable (PartitionKey: string, RowKey:string, Timestam:datetime, col1:string, col2:string) 
kind=storage  
dataformat=table
(   h@'https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mytable;secretKey')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking about [Azure *Table* Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-overview) - that is not supported as a source for an external table in Kusto.

If you choose to do so, you can ingest the data from the Azure Table into Kusto (e.g. using Azure Data Factory).

Comment: Ok, using ADF is a good workaround. Thanks, Mr. Leibowitz !